# d3 returns error `e is not a function` while passing nest data to d3.stack

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The following code is throwing the error `e is not a function` from D3:

```
var stack = d3.stack()
    .offset("zero")
    .keys(Object.keys(data[0]))(nest);
```

The below images show the error in detail:

[image: This is the error when I run it.]

[image: error is taking to d3.min.js]

[image: Formatted code in browser]

This is the error when I run it, the error appears in d3.min.js. How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm using d3.js version 5

Comment: The edits in this question make absolutely no sense. The original question asks about a stack generator, but the edited question asks about a donut chart, which is a **completely different** question and invalidate the (deleted) answer. I rolled it back and voted to undelete the answer. Please **do not edit it again**, I won't get in an edit war here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v3 of d3, with `d3.layout.stack()`, an offset value could be provided with a string:

> If offset is specified, sets the stack offset algorithm to the
>   specified value. If offset is not specified, returns the current
>   offset algorithm. The following string values are supported:
>
> ```
> silhouette - center the stream, as in ThemeRiver.
> wiggle - minimize weighted change in slope.
> expand - normalize layers to fill the range [0,1].
> zero - use a zero baseline, i.e., the y-axis.
> ```
>
> In addition to a string, offset may be specified as a function. ([v3 docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Stack-Layout.md#offset))

However, you are using d3v4+ with `d3.stack()`. The change in the method name was enough to break old examples, but the method was also changed to accept only a function (or array). No string values could be used to specify offset functionality:

> If offset is specified, sets the offset accessor to the specified
>   function or array and returns this stack generator. If offset is not
>   specified, returns the current offset acccesor, which defaults to
>   stackOffsetNone; this uses a zero baseline. See stack offsets for the
>   built-in offsets. ([v5(/4) docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#stack_offset))

So in your case, you don't need to specify an offset: the default offset is a zero baseline. If you wanted another offset to give to stack.offset(), D3 comes with [a few](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#stackOffsetExpand) out of the box:

- d3.stackOffsetExpand
- d3.stackOffsetDiverging
- d3.stackOffsetNone
- d3.stackOffsetSilhouette
- d3.stackOffsetWiggle

Comment: thanks but, still my issue is not completely resolved. In returned data, 
`{0: 0,
1: NaN,
data:{}}`

Comment: first of all, what should the `keys` for `stack.keys(keys)`

Comment: This is one object in output array
`{
0: 0
1: NaN
data: {
key: "fixed",
value: 41768976384,
timestamp: Thu june 2016 01:35:00 GMT+0530
}`
also, `a is not a function` error is returning

Comment: Andrew Reid, can you help me?

Comment: Can look tomorrow, away from the computer tonight

Comment: okay i'm editing the question with little code and sample json

Comment: I need to convert this code - ```var stack = d3.stack()
    .offset("wiggle")
    .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
    .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.value; });``` - should I simply add d3.stackOffsetWiggle() ?